# Can we migrate basic Metatag data without customization?

Tags: migrations, upgrading, meta-tags

I'm ought to Migrate-upgrade from D7 to D8 and deleted **all** modules besides Metatag (and its dependencies --> Ctools and Token).

You might have an idea how could I keep all the basic Metatag data for my nodes? By "basic" I mean only to the Page-title, Page-description and Meta keywords (And maybe also the Abstract tag); Nothing beyond that.

AFAIK, as for 2016 there is no migration-path for the Metatag module and people should generally copy their metadata manually; This situation kind of negates the whole migration experience since the all issue is to migrate nodes with their most common data.

Will cherish any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a patch at https://www.drupal.org/node/2563649, currently at "Needs work".

Comment: Issue is now closed, fixed in 8.x-1.10 https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/releases/8.x-1.10